# How to `reduce` over an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, enumerable

I wonder how to use some `reduce` logic over an object rather than an array. Something like iterating over tuples represented by

`[ object_property, property_value ]`).

I tried some code like

```
var obj = { foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz' };
Array.prototype.reduce.call(obj, function(prev, val) {
    console.log('new iteration');
    // whatever code ...
    return prev;
}, []);
```

but it doesn't perform any iteration. I can't understand why.

Maybe because the object properties are not enumerable?

**Is there any way to run a reduce function on an object?**

*Note:* There is no specific final purpose; I am exploring what's possible or what might be better patterns.

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce()` assumes the context has a `length` property and keys `[0..length - 1]`

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: No expected output; that's not the problem. I want to know if it is possible to iterate with reduce, regardless what's the operation in the callback.

Comment: Also `reduce` expects that your callback `return`s the new value of the accumulator. I think you shouldn't be using `reduce` here at all.

Comment: @Bergi you are right, I forgot it (I'll edit). As I said, the callback code is not my issue here, that's just one example.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish on running reduce in an object? What's the desired final result? Reduce objetive is obtaining an unique value. If you want to iterate .map is more adequate.

Comment: `.map` returns an array with same `length` as the original. I actually *want* a single value. There's no return value to accomplish, I already mentioned it; I am just experimenting with Javascript. - But, well, everybody keeps focusing on what the callbacks should return. The answer is, as you said: "a single, reduced value". - Specifically, I want to **directly** `return` the processing of a single statement (like a function call; e.g. `reduce()` in this case), without having to first create a temporary variable, execute a `for-of` loop to initialize it, finally return it and GC the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array methods like [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can only operate on arrays or array-like objects (with `length` and numeric properties).

You can call [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get an array of an object's property values.

Answer (score 3):

Several mistakes.

- obj is not an array. Use .values()
- The result of prev.push is not the array, is the result of the push method which is 1 (integer);
- there is no var to get the final result.

Here is a working example:

```js
var obj = { foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz' };
var res = Array.prototype.reduce.call(Object.values(obj), function(prev, val) {
    prev.push(val);
    return prev;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

I don't know why you are using `Array.prototype.reduce.call`. There's no need to call it this way. Maybe you're experimenting with js or something. 
Also `prev` is not a good name. Remember that it accumulates values, it's not just the previous interaction's value. Anyway, this is an easier way to do it:

```js
var obj = { foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz' };
var res = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, val)=>{
    acc.push(val); 
    return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

But if this is the answer you want, reduce is not needed at all. Look:

```js
var obj = { foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz' };
console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

Comment: All correct answers, but focused on the wrong things. I fixed the return value, though, thank you. The question is about how to (if possible) to run a reduce over an object; it is not about getting the an object values. Yes: the question is because I am experimenting with Javascript and the question is a pure curiosity. The note about the naming is true as well, but I explicitly chose to not induce focus toward the inside of callback, so I named it just to underline its role as accumulator. By the way, imo the correct answer is the detail about the missing `length` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `reduce()` method on the array returned by `Object.keys()` function. It looks like this:

```
var obj = { foo: 'fooValue', bar: 'barValue' };
var str = Object.keys(obj).reduce((accum, key)=>{
    return accum + obj[key];
}, '');
// str = 'fooValuebarValue';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
Object.keys(obj) which will give you array of property names on that array you can apply  any array method(predefined)
like this

```js
var obj = { foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz' };
var prev=[] //let say prev is array in which you want to store some property value

Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(element) {
    // you can have condition here as well
    prev.push(obj[element]);
});
```

but be careful if you just want to populate another array then you can use other array method like filter,map,forEach(just for learning purpose because it similar to for loop)
it would make sense.